# Missing frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, xcode5

I'm trying to integrate Admob into my app. As i'm reading the documentation, it's written that the app might require the following frameworks if they were not added: AVFoundation, adSupport, MessageUI. I turned into my app Summery to add them and i i couldn't find them. Not that i don't know how to add search/add framework, but i can't find them! i'm working with xCode 5.0 on the iMac (where the framework is missing) and on my macbook i have xCode 5.0.2 (which has the following frameworks). is it something concerning the xCode versions? is there a way to get them back?

Here is a pic trying to ad AdSupport

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They're there for me when I do the following

> 1. In the project navigator, select your project
> 2. Select your target
> 3. Select the 'Build Phases' tab
> 4. Open 'Link Binaries With Libraries' expander
> 5. Click the '+' button
> 6. Select your framework

Comment: i did the exact same thing it's not there!

Comment: ya there is but the ones i mentioned are not there. please see the pic that i added.

Comment: That says to me that you need to download and reinstall xcode the libraries haven't been downloaded correctly.

Comment: ya actually that's what i'm going to do. :/

Answer (score 0):

Okay i solved this problem by reinstalling xCode.